# PyNaCl failed to import SealedBox

Tags: pynacl

My code fails with this line:
`from nacl.public import PrivateKey, SealedBox`

I got this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'SealedBox'

I am using Python 3.6.  Anyone has any idea how this happen?

Answer (score 0):

What's your version of PyNaCl? According to the Changelog in  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyNaCl/1.2.0 the `SealedBox` support was introduced in 1.2.0. Maybe your version is older than that.

> Changelog
>   1.2.0 - 2017-11-01
>       [...]
>
> ```
> Added support for SealedBox construction.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  It has been a while.  I may get back to PyNaCl sometimes in the future.